# How to animate setInterval used to make an Image slider using javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

The images are changing suddenly and I want them to have **slide effect.**

**HTML**

```
<div><img src="1.jpg" id="sliderImage"></div>
```

This is the **script** I'm using:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("sliderImage");
var imageArray = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage() {
                        myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
                        imageIndex++;
                        if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length){imageIndex = 0;}
                        }

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to put use css for transition effect and javascript to set a timer. Also it helps to organize your elements inside a list. 
You can't see the images in the code below because of same origin policy. Try it locally and download the images and it should work.

Here is a simple slider I have built https://github.com/rotexhawk/Javascript-Practice/tree/master/slider-simple

```js
document.ready = function(){
 
 var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slider li'); 
 
 var position = 0; 
 slides[position].style.transition = '0s';
 slides[position].style.left = '1200px'; 

 var myInterval = setInterval(startSlider,4000);
 
 function startSlider(){
  
  if (position == 3){
   slides[position].style.transition = '0s';
   slides[position].style.left = '1200px'; 
   
   position = 0; 

   slides[position].style.transition = '2s';
   slides[position].style.left = 0; 

  }

  else{
   slides[position].style.transition = '0s';
   slides[position].style.left = '1200px'; 
   
   position ++; 

   slides[position].style.transition = '2s';
   slides[position].style.left = 0;
  }

 }



}();
```

```css
.container{
 width: 1200px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 padding: 5%;
}

#slider{
    width: 1200px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider li{
 width: 100%; 
 position: absolute;
 left: 1200px; 
 top: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity:0;
 transition: 2s;
}

#slider li img{
 width: 100%;
}

#slider-buttons ul{
 text-align: center;
}
#slider-buttons ul li{
 display: inline-block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 3px solid #afafaf;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#slider-buttons ul li.active{
 background-color: #249CD8;
}

#slider-buttons ul li:hover{
 background-color: #676767;
}

#effects{
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#effects h4, #effects select{
 display: inline-block;
}

 #effects select{
  min-width: 150px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <h1 class="page-title underline-text">Simple Slider</h1> 
 
 <div class="slider-container">
 
 <ul id="slider">
  <li><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rotexhawk/Javascript-Practice/master/slider-simple/images/slider1.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rotexhawk/Javascript-Practice/master/slider-simple/images/slider2.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rotexhawk/Javascript-Practice/master/slider-simple/images/slider3.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rotexhawk/Javascript-Practice/master/slider-simple/images/slider4.jpg"></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="slider-buttons"></div>
 </div>
```